# nHibernate second level cache not working on query over

Tags: c#, postgresql, caching, nhibernate

I have the following problem. 
I've enabled the second level caching system on nHibernate (using Postgres) with the following
configurations

```
cfg.SessionFactory().Caching.Through<RtMemoryCacheProvider>().WithDefaultExpiration(28800);
```

I'm enabling only enabling entity caching because i do not need query caching at this point.

In my entities here are my settings (they are some are read-write, some are read-only, more can be made read-only at this point)

```
<id name="StudentID" access="property" column="`StudentID`">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<property name="Name" column="`Name`" >
<property name="Address" column="`Address`" />
<property name="IsActive" column="`IsActive`" />
<property name="DateCreated" column="`DateCreated`" />
<property name="DateLastUpdated" column="`DateLastUpdated`" />
<property name="LastUpdatedBy" column="`LastUpdatedBy`" />

<set name="Projects" inverse="true" mutable="false">
  <cache usage="read-only"/>
  <key column="`StudentID`" />
  <one-to-many class="Project" />
</set>

<set name="Classes" inverse="true" mutable="false">
  <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
  <key column="`StudentID`" />
  <one-to-many class="Class" />
</set>

<set name="Books" inverse="true" mutable="false">
  <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
  <key column="`StudentID`" />
  <one-to-many class="Book" />
</set>
</class>
```

When unit testing my solution - i first pre-fetch a list of students, and then try to generate
a cache hit

```
public bool PreLoadStudents()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        IList<Student> results = session.QueryOver<Student>()
                                 .Fetch(d => d.Projects).Eager
                                 .Fetch(d => d.Classes).Eager
                                 .Fetch(d => d.Books).Eager
                                 .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                                 .List<Student>();
     }
}

[Test]
public void GetByIdTest()
{
   bool bLoaded = testBLL.PreLoadStudents();

   var student1 = testBLL.GetByID("123");
   var student2 = testBLL.GetByID("123");

   long cacheHit = testBLL.GetSessionFactory().Statistics.SecondLevelCacheHitCount;

   Assert.That(cacheHit,Is.EqualTo(2));    
}
```

I've tried out two different implementation of "GetByID", one of them uses
the convention "get" method, the other uses the query over method with fetch statements similar
to the PreLoadStudents student method.

In the case of "get" method, both cache hit occurred and the test passes.
In the case of "query over", no cache hit or misses occur, but 2 queries were executed instead.

Here's the code i used for the "GetByID" method using the "Get" method

```
var student = session.Get<Student>(studentId);
```

I do not prefer this method because i'm unable to fetch child collections that are lazy-loaded

Here's the code i used for the "GetByID" method using the "QueryOver" method

```
 var student = session.QueryOver<Student>()
                                          .Where(d => d.studentId == currentStudentId)
                                          .Fetch(d => d.Projects).Eager
                                          .Fetch(d => d.Classes).Eager
                                          .Fetch(d => d.Books).Eager
                                          .SingleOrDefault();
```

**Any thoughts on why the "get" method generated a hit while the query over method did not?**

Comment: Have you enabled the query cache? There's a difference between the second level cache and the query cache. Additionally, you will have to use `.Cacheable()` with your QueryOver query.

Comment: Yes - after a few tries i did enabled both query caching and entity caching. Suffice to say that i now understand query over vs get. Also, i learn that the query cache will populate the results using data from the second level cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading and doing some experimental testing, here's the solution that emerged for my question.

My initial question - *Any thoughts on why the "get" method generated a hit while the query over method did not?* is a mis-informed question, here's why:

1. Second level cache (L2) in nHibernate caches the values of the entities
2. Query cache in nHibernate caches the index of the search result

Thus

1. Get allows us to quickly retrieve an entity if we know the *id*. If
   we do not know the id then we will need to do a query that will hit
   the database if it has not been ran before. The alternative to this is to load all from the cache and then run LINQ on top of it.
2. Query over allows us to store query results in the query cache that can be populated from the L2 cache.

Lessons learned

1. Turn on both L2 cache and query cache if you want to cache queries, query cache without L2 probably doesn't improve the performance much
2. L2 can only be accessed with a cached query or via GET

Answer (score 1):

Second-level cache only works if you have a transaction, which is also a good practice around queries anyway.

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    IList<Student> results = session.QueryOver<Student>()
                             .Fetch(d => d.Projects).Eager
                             .Fetch(d => d.Classes).Eager
                             .Fetch(d => d.Books).Eager
                             .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                             .List<Student>();

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Comment: my question has nothing to do with committing transaction. Second level cache can be used in queries too.